# Meson creates build files which will not compile

Tags: c++, linux, build, centos, meson-build

I am trying to port an existing code tree to the meson build system on a centos 7 machine.  Meson configure works fine, but when I try to compile, it fails.  The code is proprietary, so I have created an example that illustrates the problem (accurately enough, I hope.)  I am not at liberty to restructure the directory tree.

Here's the tree:

```
mesonex/
    alpha/
        beta/
            alpha/
                inc/
                    funcs.h
                    numbers.h
                src/
                    numbers.cpp
                    funcs.cpp
        src/
            example.cpp
            meson.build
```

---

My meson.build:

```
project('example', 'cpp')

srcs=['example.cpp']

srcs+='../beta/alpha/src/funcs.cpp'

srcs+='../beta/alpha/src/funcs.cpp'

incdirs=include_directories('../beta/alpha/inc')

executable('example', srcs, include_directories: incdirs)
```

---

here is the main example.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "../beta/alpha/inc/numbers.h"
#include "../beta/alpha/inc/funcs.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
    std::cout << interestingNumber() << std::endl;
    std::cout << interestingFunc() << std::endl;
}
```

---

These are the supporting cpp files:

```
// funcs.cpp
#include "../inc/numbers.h"

float interestingFunc()
{
    return (interestingNumber()+1)/2;
}

// numbers.cpp

float interestingNumber()
{
    return 11.3355;
}
```

---

And these are the header files:

```
// funcs.h

float interestingFunc();

// numbers.h

float interestingNumber();
```

---

Please note that the duplication in directory names is intentional.  Maybe this confuses meson in figuring out how to handle the #includes?

This is just one example of many different build strategies I have tried.

Comment: In what way does it fail? What are the compiler error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see right off the bat an issue that might just be an issue with your example, and not with your actual code: Meson considers the meson.build file with the `project()` call to be the "root" of the source directory structure. You cannot ask it to include files outside of the root. It would be about like `cp /../foo .` on a Unix-like OS. This may just be a mistake in your example, since this isn't the real code of course.

So, if we rewrite this as (mesonex/alpha/meson.build):

```
# no project(), that would be in mesonex/meson.build)

sources = files(
  'example.cpp',
  '../beta/alpha/src/funcs.cpp',
  '../beta/alpha/src/numbers.cpp',  # you have a typo in your example, funcs.cpp is listed twice.
)

executable(
  'example',
  sources,
  include_directories : include_directories('../beta/alpha/inc'),
)
```

Should work.

Note, that you might want to consider using a convenience static library instead of reaching back to the code, as this is best practice, you could write something like (mesonex/alpha/beta/meson.build):

```
lib_beta = static_library(
  'beta',
  ['src/funcs.cpp', 'src/numbers.cpp']
)

idep_beta = declare_dependency(
  link_with : lib_beta,
  include_directories : include_directories('.'),
)
```

and then in (src/meson.build):

```
executable(
  'example',
  'source.cpp',
  dependencies : idep_beta
)
```

is all you need, as the `idep_beta` carries both the linkage and the include information.

Comment: Thanks!  That indeed works for my example.  I thought I had tried something similar on the actual code, but perhaps I flubbed the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a follow on - the solution worked for my example but not for the actual code.  My model must have been incomplete (in a way I haven't determined yet.)  The configuration stage works, but in the compile stage the #includes in the cpp source are flagged with a "File or directory does not exist."  How does meson reconcile the specified include directories with #include statements in the source?  The #include paths may be relative to the actual directory of the actual cpp source.  Does this mean I have to edit all the #includes in all the sources - that would be a real negative.  We work with some VERY large code bases.

Comment: Meson does this with `include_directories()`, each path passed to that function will become a `-I` argument pointing to both the source and build directories in your tree. So if you have `#include "a/b/c.h"` and `#include "b/d.h"` in the same file, you would need something like `include_directories('.', 'a')`. All functions that take an include_directories take arrays thereof.